# Running a while loop inside flask method

Tags: python, flask, chatbot

I am working on a chatbot and I want to link my chatbot model to a web UI(index.html). I'm new to flask and python. I need to get the user input from the web interface and send it to the model as 'user_input'. Then I need to get the response which is 'answer', and send both user_input and answer as a POST  into the newly rendered index.html. Since the answer is generated inside a while loop, I can't send it as a POST request while still running the while loop. The user_input is used inside this while loop to generate answer.

```
def chatbot(net, sess, chars, vocab, max_length, beam_width, relevance, temperature, topn):
    states = initial_state_with_relevance_masking(net, sess, relevance)

    user_input = ''
    answer = ''

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/home')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)

    while True:

        @app.route('/process',methods=['POST'])
        def process():
            user_input=request.form['user_input']
            return user_input, render_template('index.html', user_input=user_input)
            #return render_template('index.html', user_input=user_input)

        if user_input == 'GoodBye':
            break
        user_command_entered, reset, states, relevance, temperature, topn, beam_width = process_user_command(
            user_input, states, relevance, temperature, topn, beam_width)
        if reset: states = initial_state_with_relevance_masking(net, sess, relevance)
        if not user_command_entered:
            states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, sanitize_text(vocab, "> " + user_input + "\n>"))
            computer_response_generator = beam_search_generator(sess=sess, net=net,
                initial_state=copy.deepcopy(states), initial_sample=vocab[' '],
                early_term_token=vocab['\n'], beam_width=beam_width, forward_model_fn=forward_with_mask,
                forward_args={'relevance':relevance, 'mask_reset_token':vocab['\n'], 'forbidden_token':vocab['>'],
                                'temperature':temperature, 'topn':topn})
            out_chars = []
            for i, char_token in enumerate(computer_response_generator):
                out_chars.append(chars[char_token])
                #print(possibly_escaped_char(out_chars), end='', flush=True)
                states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, chars[char_token])
                if i >= max_length: break
            answer = ''.join(out_chars)
            print('Bot:' + answer)
            states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, sanitize_text(vocab, "\n> "))
```

Below is the HTML code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Friend Chatbot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
User: {{user_input}}
</div>
<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
  Freind: {{answer}}
</div>


    <form  action="/process" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Friend Chatbot</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_input" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Talk to my friend"><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to get both user_input and answer to the index.html webpage as POST requests, with each and every repetition in the while loop. I tried to put the POST flask method inside the while loop but it doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: the way your code is indented right now, nothing would be running it all. Are you sure your file looks exactly like that?

Comment: yes it is. Without the flask code segments, the python code runs perfectly. This is just the chatbot() code segment, there's lot more. The chatbot runs perfectly in the console. But I need to get the conversations to a web interface

Comment: usually, flask code will be in its own dedicated file at top level.. depending on how your server works, it might even be necessary. consider bringing your code in such a format (similar to what to the [official quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) describes), if only to make it easier for people here to help you since that's what they'll be familiar with.

Comment: I understand. I'm sorry if the code is unclear. Can you tell me a way to output the answer(to send it as a POST to the index.html) generated in each iteration in the while loop? I just don't know how to do that. while loop is how the conversation between user and model takes place. Each iteration gets user input and generates an answer as output and the cycle repeats again

Comment: JonBett's answer is pretty much exactly the way I'd expect a flask server to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems I can see here:

1. Many things here are mixed together that should be separated out
2. The loop you need is formed by the user making requests to flask, not with a while
3. This doesn't really take account of the asynchronous nature of web-requests (but that might be ok)

First things first, it's probably more confusing than it needs to be to mix together the responsibility of generating responses and the task of serving web requests. So to begin we will split off the chat bot portion:

```py
def get_chatbot(net, sess, chars, vocab, max_length, beam_width, relevance, temperature, topn):
    states = initial_state_with_relevance_masking(net, sess, relevance)

    def get_response(user_input):
        nonlocal states
        if user_input == 'GoodBye':
            # What do we expect to happen here?
            return

        user_command_entered, reset, states, relevance, temperature, topn, beam_width = process_user_command(
            user_input, states, relevance, temperature, topn, beam_width)

        if reset: 
            states = initial_state_with_relevance_masking(net, sess, relevance)

        if not user_command_entered:
            states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, sanitize_text(vocab, "> " + user_input + "\n>"))
            computer_response_generator = beam_search_generator(sess=sess, net=net,
                initial_state=copy.deepcopy(states), initial_sample=vocab[' '],
                early_term_token=vocab['\n'], beam_width=beam_width, forward_model_fn=forward_with_mask,
                forward_args={'relevance':relevance, 'mask_reset_token':vocab['\n'], 'forbidden_token':vocab['>'],
                                'temperature':temperature, 'topn':topn})
            out_chars = []
            for i, char_token in enumerate(computer_response_generator):
                out_chars.append(chars[char_token])
                #print(possibly_escaped_char(out_chars), end='', flush=True)
                states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, chars[char_token])
                if i >= max_length: break

            states = forward_text(net, sess, states, relevance, vocab, sanitize_text(vocab, "\n> "))
            return ''.join(out_chars)

    return get_response
```

This is a function which returns a function which will take user input and provide an answer. As it forms a closure around the state and other variables it will remember all the args and previous state. (Seeing as this is true, this looks like a great candidate for a `class` instead).

Now we can worry about serving the web-content separately:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
chatbot = get_chatbot(... args here ...)


@app.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    user_input = request.form['user_input']

    answer = chatbot(user_input)
    if answer is None:
        # Really do you want to bail out here?
        exit()

    return user_input, render_template(
        'index.html', user_input=user_input, answer=answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Notice here that all the code that was outside of the `process()` function is now executed inside it by calling `chatbot()`. This was the major reason you wouldn't see any output.

So where did the loop go? Well running flask forms an event loop. It is always waiting for input and providing output. The major difference is that this loop is *asynchronous*, meaning many things can happen at once, and out of order.

If you are slowly chatting to your bot by yourself, this might not matter, but if you make two requests quickly one after another, or have two people chatting at the same time, this is going to become a bigger problem. Handling that requires getting more fancy by, for example, giving each user a unique "conversation" id or something similar, and then tracking their states separately for each.

Comment: I'm getting this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'states' referenced before assignment" when the code is executed and "states, relevance, temperature, topn, beam_width)" gets underlined saying "referenced before assignment". Can you help me out to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: It's kind of hard to check this stuff, as I don't have any of the code you are using. I think it's the "reset" part which re-assigns the state and breaks the enclosed variable. I'll try and change it - Edit - Updated: look at the `nonlocal states` bit